# How to use arrays 2048 Game clone - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have made a [2048 Game](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) clone, part of which deals with moving and combining the blocks. This is in VB.NET, .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2013.

**How do I use arrays in my code? It additionally has the following problem:**

The code seems to work fine for the uppermost column when moving up, and the leftmost when moving left, etc., but it doesn't do anything for the next columns, although they are in fact direct derivatives (ie copy + paste with a little change to adapt it) of the uppermost, leftmost etc. column. I have double checked, triple checked and 100 times checked but I still can't see the fault in my program. I'm hoping that using arrays might fix this.

Any help with this greatly appreciated!

Here is an extract of the code. It is the moving and combining part of the "Move Up" sub. (It uses a 4x4 block grid where Label1 is the top left block, Label2 to the right of that, Label3 to the right of Label2 and Label5 is below Label1, Label9 is below Label5, etc.)

```
   If Label1.Text = Label5.Text And Not Label1.Text = "" And Not Label5.Text = "" Then
        Dim result As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Label5.Text)
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result)
        Label5.Text = ""
    End If
```

Here is a further extract from this sub, the part where the blocks are moved ("gravitated") upwards as far as possible. It's repeated several times to make sure nothing is missed out/not moved as far as possible.

```
    If Label1.Text = "" Then
        Label1.Text = Label5.Text
        Label5.Text = Label9.Text
        Label9.Text = Label13.Text
        Label13.Text = ""
    End If
```

**I want to know how to implement arrays into this, hopefully thereby improving it to make it work correctly for all the columns**. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: First I'd try simplifying the code by introducing integer varabiles and tryparsing into those, then you don't need you if statements and multiple conversions of the same text box. Then you will have something more manageable to work with.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of the existing 2048 games to see how they work? This should give you insight into how to potentially make things better.

Comment: @chris yes but it's in JavaScript, so i can't use it. Besides, it uses variables which I don't understand where they have come from.

Comment: @Chris like the boolean 'occupied' or something similar. I can easily guess its function but couldn't find where/how it's changed, so I can't do much with it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd suggest is using a custom class for the labels.  This has several advantages.  It's easier to create the collections you'll need and you can modify it for your particular needs.  In this case I would suggest a `Value` property of type integer and suppressing access to the `Text` property and a Dictionary for the color scheme:

```
Public Class GameLabel
    Inherits Label
    Private ReadOnly ColorScheme As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Color) From
        {
            {0, SystemColors.Control},
            {2, System.Drawing.Color.Beige},
            {4, System.Drawing.Color.SaddleBrown},
            {8, System.Drawing.Color.Orange},
            {16, System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange},
            {32, System.Drawing.Color.Red},
            {64, System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed},
            {128, System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow},
            {256, System.Drawing.Color.Yellow},
            {512, System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow},
            {1024, System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen},
            {2048, System.Drawing.Color.Green}
        }
    Public Property Value As Integer
        Get
            If MyBase.Text = "" Then
                Return 0
            Else
                Return Integer.Parse(Text)
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value = 0 Then
                Text = ""
            Else
                Text = value.ToString
            End If
            BackColor = ColorScheme(value)
        End Set
    End Property
    'This removes the Text property from the Intellisense list. It can still be
    'used but this removes the temptation to use the text when you meant to use
    'Value.
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Dim temp As Integer = 0
            Integer.TryParse(value, temp)
            If temp = 0 Then
                MyBase.Text = ""
            Else
                MyBase.Text = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    <DefaultValue(True)>
    Public Overrides Property AutoSize As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            MyBase.AutoSize = False
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Size = New Size(78, 37)
        Font = New Font(Font.Name, 20, FontStyle.Bold)
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Text = ""
    End Sub
    'This isn't really necessary.  This allows Intellisense to show the default
    'values that I want instead of drilling through to find these properties
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Location.ToString & "/" & Value.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

For the collections now everything we want is of type `GameLabel` which simplifies building the collections:

```
    Squares = (From nl As GameLabel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GameLabel)()
               Order By nl.Location.X, nl.Location.Y
               Select nl).ToList
    Rows = (From nl As GameLabel In Squares
            Group By nl.Location.Y Into Group
            Select Group.ToList).ToList
    Columns = (From nl As GameLabel In Squares
            Group By nl.Location.X Into Group
            Select Group.ToList).tolist
```

Each of these contains the same data it's just being re-organized to simplify your code.  Now in your code you use whichever collection is organized for your needs.  Since each collection is organized by Location and we're only reading and changing the Value we don't have to worry about individual names.

One method to move the blocks and change the values is to not actually move the blocks just the values. in an individual column or row make a temporary list of all the values that aren't 0.  Do the merging and replace the values in the original list clearing any squares that won't have a value after.